# Error with isnullorempty function

Tags: asp.net, string, checkbox, boolean

I used a string to null function to check if a field should show if it has a value or not. I am placing it inside a checkbox to show that if it is not null or empty, it should show true, and if not false. I am throwing all of my data straight from my datatable to my fields.

```
<asp:CheckBox runat='server' enabled=false Checked='<%# (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("amount").ToString()) ? "False" : "True")%>' />
```

But when I test it, it shows the error `"Cannot convert type 'string' to 'bool' "`

Was using `IsNullOrempty` the best way to tackle my issue with the checkbox value?

Comment: how about this ? - <asp:CheckBox runat='server' enabled=false Checked='<%# (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("amount").ToString())%>'

Comment: @user972  I did try the code, but it seems that I need the reverse of the bool value, say if its true, I need to give false, and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then use this :

```
 <asp:CheckBox runat='server' enabled=false Checked='<%# (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("amount").ToString())%>'
```

Comment: I also found out that I could just remove the quotation marks for both the true and false values to make it work, but otherwise your answer works great. Thanks.

Comment: yes you can. But why would you add extra code if it is already done by the framework for you.